# what does remove query mean when I profiling the mongodb

Tags: mongodb, profiling

```
{ "ts" : "Mon Mar 28 2011 23:12:25 GMT+0800 (CST)", "info" : "remove  query: { taskid: \"aae7942d-0a61-4d08-8507-f92c7eebee7f\" } 403ms", "millis" : 403 }
{ "ts" : "Mon Mar 28 2011 23:11:15 GMT+0800 (CST)", "info" : "remove  query: { taskid: \"0b973bcb-52fa-4709-a9bc-47841e51a5ab\" } 171ms", "millis" : 171 }
{ "ts" : "Mon Mar 28 2011 23:11:10 GMT+0800 (CST)", "info" : "remove  query: { taskid: \"0c352958-bcd8-4e28-b9cd-7e7534580eac\" } 223ms", "millis" : 223 }
{ "ts" : "Mon Mar 28 2011 23:11:07 GMT+0800 (CST)", "info" : "remove  query: { taskid: \"0c35c0e5-3460-4192-9094-e4d0fa623470\" } 224ms", "millis" : 224 }
{ "ts" : "Mon Mar 28 2011 23:11:06 GMT+0800 (CST)", "info" : "remove  query: { roleid: \"2d1dedfe-e587-4444-9b3a-3691a4c47fde\" } 18ms", "millis" : 18 }
{ "ts" : "Mon Mar 28 2011 23:11:01 GMT+0800 (CST)", "info" : "remove  query: { taskid: \"ee3bbc78-def4-4b96-8db7-1dd12443707a\" } 325ms", "millis" : 325 }
{ "ts" : "Mon Mar 28 2011 23:10:44 GMT+0800 (CST)", "info" : "remove  query: { taskid: \"7d0d7433-4954-4355-adfa-5af2fd2c3b06\" } 357ms", "millis" : 357 }
```

I see it often when I using database profiling, and taskid is a index of a collection

I set:
db.setProfilingLevel(1,50)
and then I look into the 
db.system.profile.find().sort(ts:-1).limit(20)

I saw a lot of scary long execution like
{ "ts" : "Mon Mar 28 2011 20:42:39 GMT+0800 (CST)", "info" : "remove 
query: { taskid: \"495951f5-8042-4a7a-9f09-f65c9e622e28\" } 361ms", 
"millis" : 361 }

but currently I didn't experience abnormal slow or delay in my application.

so I just wonder why so long and what is that

here is my table status

```
> db.role_task.stats() 


{ 
        "ns" : "dt_base.role_task", 
        "count" : 17907, 
        "size" : 66267932, 
        "avgObjSize" : 3700.6719160104985, 
        "storageSize" : 86088960, 
        "numExtents" : 11, 
        "nindexes" : 3, 
        "lastExtentSize" : 20872448, 
        "paddingFactor" : 1.4199999999985065, 
        "flags" : 1, 
        "totalIndexSize" : 5496832, 
        "indexSizes" : { 
                "_id_" : 761856, 
                "taskid_1" : 1753088, 
                "roleid_1_taskdbid_1" : 2981888 
        }, 


"ok" : 1
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Removes are often slow (relies on disk speed) and should not be of concern unless your database depends heavily on them.  The default action of MongoDB is to run this remove in the background and allow your other operations to go concurrently.  This is why you do not see noticeable slowdowns.

from documentation:

> v1.3+ supports concurrent operations while a remove runs. If a simultaneous update (on the same collection) grows an object which matched the remove criteria, the updated object may not be removed (as the operations are happening at approximately the same time, this may not even be surprising). In situations where this is undesireable, pass {$atomic : true} in your filter expression: